# Is there a way to split a string into multiple strings?

Tags: mysql

I've got software running with a database behind it that saves all values in a dropdown value into one column by a GUID.
Since multiple GUIDs can be saved in this one column I need to split the string into multiple strings.

Does anyone know how to do this?
The string is as follows, but potentially can have more values than just these two (in between "" to avoid it being identified as a header.):

`#1$,{8312aeeb-3a90-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac},{2a8d152b-1ea4-4a63-ae63-db011deb6dea}`

This is for a MySQL 2012 server. I've been scouring the internet for potential solutions and most of them say to create your own split function. Sadly I don't understand what they exactly do when I read through them, thus it's difficult for me to fill in the correct names/values.

**I expect the output to be either:**

> `{8312aeeb-3a90-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac}`
>
> `{2a8d152b-1ea4-4a63-ae63-db011deb6dea}`

or

> `8312aeeb-3a90-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac`
>
> `2a8d152b-1ea4-4a63-ae63-db011deb6dea`

I'm going to use the result as a subquery. The intent is to make a fully dynamical query.

Comment: There isn't a MySQL 2012  are you sure you don't mean mssql/sqlserver.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a string split/explode function quite like PHP or many other languages do.

It can split a string on a delimiter, but doesn't allow you to access each element of the array nearly as easily.  *You say you're populating a dropdown in a GUI.  Would it be easier to use the GUI language which most likely has an easier-to-manipulate string split function?*

At the moment, I can't think of a of a way to return each element as a row, but only how to return each value in a separate column in the returned recordset.

You will need to create your own "function" within your query.  Let me see if I can show you an example, and then give more explanation than what is shown in most of the hits I found in a few minutes of looking.  BE WARNED: since your example may have 1, 2, 3...n "elements," you'll have to get really creative dealing with duplicates. -- If you set up your query to retrieve four elements from a row that has three values, the third and fourth values returned will be the same.

Most examples I found over the last few minutes do a great job of freely switching positive and negative numbers and then leave it to you to try and understand how/why/when to switch from positive to negative.

For however many elements you expect to be the maximum, use this as the model:

```
SELECT ...,    
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', n), '.', -1) as xxx,
...
FROM my_table
```

MySQL processes functions like you do in algebra - start handling inner parenthesis first and then work your way out.

The inner part of this function (SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', n)) splits the string on the '.' delimiter and then holds on to the first "n" parts.  The outer part of the function splits what it is holding in memory and then returns the last (-1) part.

Using this model, you can much more easily follow how this works, and better yet remember what you're doing now when you see this code months for now.

```
SELECT ...,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', 1), '.', -1) as guid_1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', 2), '.', -1) as guid_2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', 3), '.', -1) as guid_3,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', 4), '.', -1) as guid_4,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', 5), '.', -1) as guid_5,
...
FROM my_table
```

Handling duplicates within the query will get really messy.  Here's what it would take to return an empty string for the fifth element of a row with only four elements:

```
IF(substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', 4), '.', -1) != 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', 5), '.', -1), 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(guid, '.', 5), '.', -1), 
    '') as guid_5
```

You can simplify this a bit by creating a user function on your MySQL server if the server admin permits it.  I'd create the following function:

```
create function MY_SUBSTRING (
  search_string text,
  delimiter_chars varchar(1),
  string_index int
)
RETURNS varchar(128) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    # FIRST ARRAY ELEMENT IS INDEX 1, NOT INDEX 0
    RETURN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(search_string, delimiter_chars, string_index), delimiter_chars, -1);
END $$
```

This would give you a nice bit of clean and reusable code that would make this and other queries cleaner, such as

```
SELECT ...,
MY_SUBSTRING(guid, '.', 1) as guid_1,
MY_SUBSTRING(guid, '.', 2) as guid_2,
MY_SUBSTRING(guid, '.', 3) as guid_3,
MY_SUBSTRING(guid, '.', 4) as guid_4,
MY_SUBSTRING(guid, '.', 5) as guid_5,
...
FROM my_table
```

Whoops - I just saw that you wanted to use the results as a subquery.  That is a whole other vat of worms, and would need someone who has an idea to shift the result from columns to rows.  At the very least, I hope this helps you understand the SUBSTRING_INDEX function better.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for something like this?:

```
SELECT g.id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(',',g.myguid,','), ',', sep.id), ',' , -1) AS newguid
FROM guid g
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 3 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 ) AS sep
HAVING newguid != ''
ORDER BY g.id,sep.id;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB []> select * from guid;
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | myguid                                                                                                                                                  |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | #1$,{8312aeeb-3a90-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac},{2a8d152b-1ea4-4a63-ae63-db011deb6dea}                                                                       |
|  2 | #1$,{8312aeeb-3a90-4c56-b58e-e4597d2aFFFF}                                                                                                              |
|  3 | #1$,{8312aeeb-AAAA-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac},{BBBB-1ea4-4a63-ae63-db011deb6dea},{8312aeeb-CCCC-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac},{EEEE-1ea4-4a63-ae63-db011deb6dea} |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB []> SELECT g.id,
    ->     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(',',g.myguid,','), ',', sep.id), ',' , -1) AS newguid
    -> FROM guid g
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 3 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 ) AS sep
    -> HAVING newguid != ''
    -> ORDER BY g.id,sep.id;
+----+----------------------------------------+
| id | newguid                                |
+----+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | {8312aeeb-3a90-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac} |
|  1 | {2a8d152b-1ea4-4a63-ae63-db011deb6dea} |
|  2 | {8312aeeb-3a90-4c56-b58e-e4597d2aFFFF} |
|  3 | {8312aeeb-AAAA-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac} |
|  3 | {BBBB-1ea4-4a63-ae63-db011deb6dea}     |
|  3 | {8312aeeb-CCCC-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac} |
|  3 | {EEEE-1ea4-4a63-ae63-db011deb6dea}     |
+----+----------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to you some plan
**plan A:**
you can use select with multiple value

```
<select id='mySelect'>
    <option value="8312aeeb-3a90-4c56-b58e-e4597d2a18ac" 
            data-val1="val1" 
            data-val2="val2" 
            data-val3="val3"> item1</option>
</select>
```

and you can get value in jquery

```
var val1 = $("#mySelect option:selected").data('val1');
var val2 = $("#mySelect option:selected").data('val2');
var val3 = $("#mySelect option:selected").data('val3');
```

then send them to server

```
  PLoading.Start();
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/user/login',
                data: { val1 : val1 },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {                   

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    PAlert.ErrorAlert("بروز خطا");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    PLoading.Stop();
                }
            });
```

**plan B**
you can use new table to join `Guid` field to other field/table column
shema of new table

|Guid|val1|val2|val3|