# splitting string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a few thousand rows similar to this.  I need to extract data from the table but my destination table has a character limit (let's say 25 bytes).  I need to write a query to extract all the data but duplicate the line when the notes column exceeds the destination character limit and separate the note into chunks 1/3,2/3,3/3 etc. on each instance of the line... any suggestions?

| Name | Date | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 7/18/2023 | John came in with a small triangular bandaid stuck in his hair. We removed it with tweezers and applied apple cider vineger to maintain folical health |
| Mike Johnson | 7/18/2023 | Michael had a tiny piece of tape stuck on his cheek, which we carefully removed without causing any skin irritation. To moisturize the area, we applied a light layer of coconut oil, known for its potential nourishing properties for the skin. |
| Dan Jones | 7/18/2023 | Dan had a small sticker stuck on his forehead, and we gently peeled it off, ensuring not to cause any discomfort. To soothe the area, we applied aloe vera gel, known for its potential skin-calming properties. |

I can separate the data into separate columns using substrings but I'd like to limit my excel  w ork on the back end if possible

```
SELECT 
name
,Date
,CASE 
   WHEN Len(Notes) <= 25 THEN Note
   ELSE CONCAT('Part 1: ',SUBSTRING(Note,1,18)
   END   
,CASE 
   WHEN Len(Notes) > 25 THEN 
     CONCAT('Part 2: ',SUBSTRING(Note,19,37)
   ELSE ''
   END
,CASE   
   WHEN Len(Notes) > 37 THEN 
     CONCAT('Part 3: ',SUBSTRING(Note,38,56)
   ELSE ''
   END
,CASE
   WHEN Len(Notes) > 56 THEN 
    CONCAT('Part 4: ',SUBSTRING(Note,57,75) 
   ELSE ''
   END AS NOTE
FROM
Table 1
```

Comment: Please show definitions of your tables (in TEXT format, not as picture), and what you tried to get this working.  And idea could be to start reading this [Is there a way to split a string into multiple strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231658/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-into-multiple-strings)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: That you are using SSMS is largely irrelevant; SSMS can be used with several database products with the main one being SQL Server. What we need to know if you Database Engine provider and the version of that. Tagging SSMS for your database engine is like tagging Visual Studio for the programming language you're using.

Comment: Why do you mix `Notes` and `Note`? What is the REAL name of that column ? (for example in: `WHEN Len(Notes) <= 25 THEN Note`)

Comment: @Luuk. Notes is the column name coming from the DB and it's aptly named so I name it the same thing.  I should have named each case note 1,2,3,4 etc but I typo'd and have exceeded my edits allowed

Comment: When you have a limited-length string like 25 position, why do you add the useless text `'Part 1: '`, which occupies 8 characters of those 25 (That is **32%** of the characters that fit in that column ) Mya I suggest to add a numeric column, which hold partnumber ?

Comment: my true data cap is 7950 characters but to create a manageable dummy dataset (and avoid giving personal info away), i've just shrunk the scope and pulled data out of my ass :)

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this SSMS so I'm going to guess that you are using Microsoft SQL Server. In SQL Server 2022 you can make use of the generate_series feature. In other versions or other SQL DBMSs use a numbers table instead (i.e. one row per number).

```
/* create a table and some sample data */
CREATE TABLE foo (name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, date DATE NOT NULL, notes VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (name,date));

INSERT INTO foo (name, date, notes) VALUES
    ('John Smith','2023-07-18','Here say figurines billycoose arming and mounting')
    ,('Michael Johnson','2023-07-18','Mounting and arming bellicose figurines see here')
    ,('Dan Jones','2023-07-18','Face at the eased! O I fay!');

WITH n(num) AS (SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,10000,25))
SELECT t.name, t.date
    , num/25+1 AS chunk, SUBSTRING(t.notes, num, num+24) AS notes
FROM n, foo AS t
WHERE num <= LEN(t.notes);
```

Here's an alternative version using a [numbers table](https://github.com/dportas1/sqlcode/blob/master/numbers.sql), which should be good for any SQL DBMS:

```
WITH n(num) AS (SELECT num FROM number WHERE num%25=1)
SELECT t.name, t.date
    , num/25+1 AS chunk, SUBSTRING(t.notes, num, num+24) AS notes
FROM n, foo AS t
WHERE num <= LEN(t.notes);
```

Comment: I am using SSMS 18 (doesn't have GENERATE_SERIES). How would I do it with a number table?

Comment: @MatthewWerner I updated my answer. By the way, the availability of GENERATE_SERIES has nothing to do with what version of SSMS you are using. It is a server feature.